# Using C++ but not using the language's specific features, should switch to C?

Tags: c++, c

I'm developing a NES emulator as a hobby, in my free time.  I use C++ because is the language I use mostly, know mostly and like mostly.

But now that I made some advance into the project I realize I'm not using almost any specific features of C++, and could have done it in plain C and getting the same result. I don't use templates, operator overloading, polymorphism, inheritance. So what would you say? should I stay in C++ or rewrite it in C?

I won't do this to gain in performance, it could come as a side effect, but the idea is *why should I use C++ if I don't need it?*

The only features of C++ I'm using is classes to encapsulate data and methods, but that can be done as well with structs and functions, I'm using new and delete, but could as well use malloc and free, and I'm using inheritance just for callbacks, which could be achieved with pointers to functions.

Remember, it's a hobby project, I have no deadlines, so the overhead time and work that would require a re-write are not a problem, might be fun as well. So, the question is C or C++?

Comment: It seems to me that you have already answered yourself: why use C++ if you only need C? There are many situations in which C is perfectly OK.

Comment: @Giorgio: And they all evaporate after the first sixty seconds and you need to maintain your code.

Comment: @DeamMG: What are you referring to?

Comment: `I use C++ because is the language I use mostly, know mostly and like mostly.` And that's the answer to your question. You should only switch languages mid project when there's a problem your current language can't solve. `I don't use templates, operator overloading, polymorphism, inheritance.` It would be a lot more valuable to learn and use the concepts, than switching to C. Since this is a hobby project, why not use a few things you haven't used before? You could always start another project in C and learn the language, but for your current project it doesn't make sense to switch.

Comment: @Giorgio: That unenforced memory management and home-rolled data structures are incredibly unsafe.

Comment: I don't use 100% of a language in every project I write either. You know C++ the best, you might find good reasons to use features you haven't found a use for before. You can start treating C++ as a much safer C, once you start using the standard library stuff and boost constructs like `std::shared_ptr`, `std::unique_ptr`, `boost::scoped_ptr`, `std::vector`, `std::deque`, `std::map`, etc. For callback functions, look into the use of functors, and in C++11, you can also start using things like lambda functions.

Comment: @DeadMG: I agree that C needs more boilerplate and it more error-prone wrt memory management. What do you mean by home-rolled data structures? The absence of standard containers?

Comment: @Giorgio: Yep. Rolling the infiniteth linked list is bound to produce unnecessary errors.

Comment: Another consideration is which language will be most useful to you in the future, either for another hobby project or work.  More time spent in a language means more chance to develop expertise in it.

Comment: The question is not what you don't use/need from C++ (although I guess you would indeed need it if you knew it better, but that aside), but what C would actually buy you in addition to C++, which is just **nothing** (no, not even performance). It would be only so that you can say *"I'm writing real C and not some strange wannabe C++"*, but since C++ is a multiparadigm language anyway, this is just no argument. If you don't need/want OOP or generic programming, then don't use it, nobody is punishing you for not using the complete feature set of C++.

Comment: @ChristianRau A significant benefit to using C is that people will stop telling you to use modern C++.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You aren't using it now, but the next time you leak memory or get a double delete, you'll be begging to come back to `std::vector<T>`, `std::unique_ptr<T, Del>` and `std::shared_ptr<T>`, which can solve those problems easily- almost trivially. That's what happens to everyone who uses C over C++, eventually, and the smarter ones just don't wait for the bugs to pop up before moving over.

Code that uses `new` and `delete` directly doesn't really belong in C++, it belongs in that kind of half house that we refer to as "C with Classes". That's where the language was circa 1985. It's not particularly similar to C++, circa 2011. In all likelihood, wherever you learned C++ simply didn't teach it very well- something that is unfortunately rather common- and with a better education, you *would* find use of these features.

Specifically, as I listed above, C++'s generic data structures and the resource-managing classes simply are fundamentally massively superior to anything C has to offer. If you want a dynamically allocated array, then use `std::vector<T>`. That's a pretty common use case. If you aren't using them, then your code is at huge risk of error unnecessarily- especially resource management related. C++ can *guarantee* safety and re-use code in a way that C can never touch.

However, I think that you also might be expecting too much. Writing templates and operator overloads is not common for library consumers. If your code uses `std::vector<T>`, you don't need to *write* a template to make that happen. If your code uses `std::string`, nobody is forcing you to overload your operators. You only have to do those things to *write* `std::vector<T>` and `std::string`- but you can still take full advantage of them.

Polymorphism/inheritance also only has a specific use case. If your code happens to not require you to write any templates or use virtual functions, then it doesn't, and there are programs or segments of programs where you don't need to write your own templates.

Also, there's no gain in performance in C over C++.

Comment: I normally use smart pointers, so I do not call delete directly, but I have to call new, or how can you avoid it?

Comment: @Giorgio: `make_shared` exists, and you can write a trivial `make_unique` template that does the same job. It's safer.

Comment: Great answer. Nail on the head. C++ is most valuable for these little libraries that we should always be using.

Comment: "Also, there's no gain in performance in C over C++.": this is necessarily true since C is a subset of C++.

Comment: @DeadMG: I do not want to sound pedantic, but what is unsafe about calling new when I create a smart pointer? I mean like in: boost::shared_ptr<A> ptr(new A);

Comment: @Giorgio you can avoid new operator using factory method or abstract factory design patterns.

Comment: Ok, then I have to use the new operator in the factory implementation. But my question was why it is unsafe if I use it only in the constructor of a smart pointer.

Comment: Your factory normally will go to your library (module) that means that you will avoid using it (new) in your normal app project. no it is not unsafe but in case you export a class from dll probably you will need to throw exception on your constructor but cross module exceptions and class exporting is bad practice in c++.

Comment: @Alex Theodoridis: Do you know any link to some web page where I can read more on these subjects (cross module exceptions and class exporting)?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/howto_export_cpp_classes.aspx

Comment: @Giorgio: It's unsafe because when calling multiple arguments like that, you can get a memory leak in the case of exception, and `make_shared` is more efficient. Only factory functions can offer guaranteed exception safety.

Comment: -1 because it divides c++ features to some groups which do not make much sense. (all c++ features are there for a reason, and everyone should do their own choice which subset to use)

Comment: @tp1: WTF? In English, please.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I've coded a lot in C++ and wasn't at all aware that direct use of new and delete was discouraged, so I may have to go back to reading a bit of up-to-date C++ books, what do you suggest?

Comment: @Petruza: There is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) which has been vetted by the SO C++ community to contain good books. Also, feel free to come join us in the chat and we'll lend you a hand.

Comment: "Also, there's no gain in performance in C over C++." [citation needed]

Comment: @Lohoris You don't need a citation for common sense. In which way should C be more performant than C++?

Answer (score 7):

Even if you don't use C++ specific features, a C++ compiler will catch more problems than a C one due to the stricter type system of C++.

Answer (score 6):

I would look at it from the other direction. Will you *gain* anything by rewriting the code in C? Even on a purely hobbyist project, there's a cost associated with a rewrite like that. If nothing else there's what I suppose would be called opportunity cost -- i.e., the other things you could have done in that time if you weren't <strike>wasting your time</strike> rewriting it in C.

Bottom line: unless you think the code is really likely to be used in some environment where access to C++ is really limited (or nonexistent), it would be a pointless waste of time at very best. At least in my experience, it usually goes well beyond that very quickly -- thinking back over code I've written in C++ that *had* to be converted to C, I can pretty clearly remember that even in quite a few cases where it seemed like it should be trivial, I was using a lot more features specific to C++ than I initially realized. To have much hope of being useful at all, you'd pretty much have to target C89/90, in which case you quickly get reminded of things like having to define all variables at the beginning of a block instead of where they're actually used.

In short, unless you're pretty sure rewriting in C will provide a real benefit, there are almost inevitably a lot better things to do.

Comment: +1 Some time ago I had to write a library to be used in another C project and I thought it was a good idea to also implement it in C, man what a stupid idiot I was back then.

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to answer your questions, since we don't know if you are working on the project to improve your language specific skills (C vs C++) or to improve other programming skills (design, problem-solving, etc.).

**"The only features of C++ I'm using is classes to encapsulate data and methods, but that can be done as well with structs and functions,".** This is not true. `structs` in C do not support encapsulation and cannot contain functions (methods) - at least not without using techniques like pointers to functions. Also, functions in C are weaker because they cannot be overloaded.

**"I'm using new and delete, but could as well use malloc and free, and I'm using inheritance just for callbacks, which could be achieved with pointers to functions.".** As deadmg mentioned, using directly `new` and `delete` in C++ is not encouraged. Also, IMHO (and the GoF) inheritance in OOP should be preferred over composition only when polymorphism is required. And I don't think that it is trivial to achieve polymorphism (late binding) in C using pointers to functions.

Other than that, I'll not try to convince you that C++ is "better" than C because it's a matter of preference and it always depends on the problem that you are trying to solve (using OOP features for developing your NES emulator might be a good idea).

Comment: `structs` in C can, in fact, be used to encapsulate methods. You simply create a struct of function pointers, and initialize them to point to whichever functions you want. Have a look at http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.3/include/linux/fs.h#L1598 for an example.

Comment: That's right. Thanks for the comment, I extended the answer.

Comment: Nice. One more nit: functions in C _can_ be overloaded (think `printf`), but in doing so you lose any type checking. There is no way to have a finite set of acceptable declarations: it's either 1 (and you get type checking) or "many" (and lose all type checking, at great personal risk). As with most things in C, it's _possible_ but often uncomfortable.

Comment: Pointers to functions are an advanced C technique? Really?

Comment: @DonalFellows You are right, I exaggerated. Removed advanced... :)

Comment: Well, it's not as convenient as class encapsulation, but imagine that you have `struct sometype; void sometype_dosomething( sometype* this );` That's very close to class encapsulation, as long as you prefix _methods_ with the struct name and the first argument is always a pointer to the struct.

Answer (score 1):

**As a more general answer:**

Do not switch to C++ just because you are using some of it's more unique features. One day you may need those features, and will just pound your head because you are using C.

Answer (score 1):

For hobbyist development, I would consider switching back to plain C.  C and C-like languages are more likely to be supported on tiny hobby development modules.

Many of the answers here might be from professional software types.  As a hobbyist, you won't be coding continuously or full time.  So consider which language you are more likely to remember or forget the quirks within, if you table your project for a year and then come back and try to read your code after you have gotten rusty in coding.  C++, having a richer feature set, may take more or less time to re-acquire, depending on your coding style.

Answer (score 0):

I am a very beginner, so here comes my 2 bits.

I am learning C and C++ at Wibit.net with some nice basic videotutorials, maybe they can help you a lot to take a overview of the "situation" (not an ad!)

I advice you to change to C, just to learn, as you are a hobbyist, this will be a pleasure, not a problem.

I advice more. Do it in both languages. Compare the way and solutions you will find and use. I am sure it will be not "so easy" as you are expecting... but sure you will learn a lot!

Comment: Thank you very much, but I'm not learning, I already know C and C++, I'm asking which one to use for this specific project.

Comment: oops, my time to learn! =P

Comment: Also, I would advice that instead of video tutorials, you get Kernigan's and Stroustrup's books, a nice IDE (Visual Studio, Eclipse, Xcode) and learn by coding the examples, trial and error and resorting to stackoverflow.

Answer (score -1):

Here's pros and cons of C++ vs. C:

1. Moving to C would make it easier to stay within the chosen C++ subset, because compiler would then give error when you go outside of it. If the main problem is with staying within decided subset, this alternative should be chosen. (why don't we have compiler support for this?)
2. Once you can stay within chosen c++ feature subset, then next thing is to try to change the subset to get rid of bad conventions which break the code. This requires use of whole c++.
3. Once you have both "staying inside subset" and "it's a good subset", then move outside of c++ features, and start thinking about requirements.